# Find $a\in\mathbb{R}, a\neq 0$ such that the parabolas of the functions $f$ and $g$ are tangent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, tangent-line

> Find $a\in\mathbb{R}, a\neq 0$ such that the parabolas of the functions $f$ and $g$ are tangent.

$f_a(x)=ax^2-(a+2)x-1$.

$g_a(x)=x^2-x-a$.

At first what I tried is find their derivative and just make them equal, but it's nowhere near the good answer...

What I tried:

since they must be tangent I thought their derivative should be equal so we have:

$f_a'(x)=2ax-(a+2)$ and $g_a'(x)=2x-1$ by making them equalling we get $a = 1$ and $a = -1$ at the same time... which is completely wrong (that's why I didn't added this).

Following B.Metha's advice we have:

$f_a(x) - g_a(x) = (a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+a-1.$

Comment: Their derivatives must be equal *at the same point* ...

Comment: So take $x_0$ as the point is still no good.

Comment: Find the intersection of $g_a$ and $f_a$ and then calculate the angle between them at that point

Comment: Try working out $f_a(x) - g_a(x)$

Comment: @B.Mehta I did.

Comment: I know you said that you tried to find their derivative, but since you didn't write it down I have a hard time believing that you actually found them?

Comment: @C.Cristi How are we to know that you followed B. Mehta's advice?  There is nothing in your question that indicates that you have done anything other than "tried to find their derivative and make them equal."  Even there, you have not shown what you actually did.

Comment: Can you think of a useful property of $f_a - g_a$ that would give what you're looking for?

Comment: I did not added what I actually tried because I am ashamed by it because it is just plain wrong... please verify the edit..

Comment: Your edit is immensely helpful for yourself, because now we can clearly see what is your error in reasoning, and can specifically tell you. I don't have time to write a full answer, but basically tangency does not mean they have to have equal gradient everywhere. It only means that they have to have equal gradient at the point[s] where they meet.

Comment: @user21820 When I first read the problem, I also thought they should be tangent only in 1 point but I got confused by the lack of "information" in the problem.. and thought they must have the same tangent everywhere...

Comment: @C.Cristi Part of learning is being wrong (often, quite wrong in quite embarrassing ways).  The only way to get better is to show of your ignorance, so that others can help you patch things together.  Your willingness to share your thoughts have vastly improved this question.

Comment: Ah I see. Well "curves A,B are tangent at P" conventionally means that at P the curves A,B have the same gradient. They are even allowed to intersect elsewhere.

Comment: @user21820 I understand now, thank you for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\in\mathbb R$, then the parabolas are tangent if and only if they have one and only one point in common. So, when is it true that the equation$$ax^2-(a+2)x-1=x^2-x-a$$has one and only one solution? That's when the discriminant of $(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+a-1$ is $0$. That happens if and only if $a=\frac13$ or $a=3$.

Comment: I understood that if they are tangent then in *that point* call it $x_0$ the functions $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$, but in the last relation why must be the *discriminant* $\delta=0$? Oh I think i understood now, so the equation must have only *a single* point (root)? so the tangent point must be unique?

Comment: @C.Cristi: While this answer happens to be correct, it did not justify the claim in the very first line. As I stated elsewhere, two curves can be tangent at some point even if they intersect at another point. So it is in general incorrect to assume that tangency implies unique intersection.

Comment: @C.Cristi More complex curves can be tangent at a point and still have other points in common, but two parabolas are tangent if and only if thet have one and only one point in common. This has the advantage that there is no need to compute derivatives.

Comment: @user21820 I agree *in general*, but not for parabolas.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I think I understand now

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: But my point is that your answer is incomplete. It's like saying "**obviously**" to avoid giving a proof...

Comment: @user21820 I don't think so, but if you (or someone else) want a proof, here's one: if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are quadratics with two distinct points in common $a$ and $b$, then $p(x)-q(x)$ is a quadratic with two distinct roots $a$ and $b$. Therefore, the only point $c$ such that $(p-q)'(c)=0$ is $\frac{a+b}2$. In particular, $p'(a)\neq q'(a)$ and $p'(b)\neq q'(b)$, and therefore the graphs of $p(x)$ and of $q(x)$ are not tangent.

Comment: I know how to prove it, but did @C.Cristi? In my opinion, if you want to teach you should teach properly to impart complete understanding and not use hand-waving unnecessarily.

Comment: @user21820 I didn't... I took it "as is"

Comment: @user21820 I see now that what I wrote could be read as if I was suggesting that you didn't know how to prove it. I had no such intention. As to what the OP needed so that the answer would be considered as correct, that requires more context than the one that was provided.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by José Carlos Santos is (as of now) factually correct but arguably very incomplete because it relies on some fact that only holds for parabolas, without proving it. Here is a much simpler approach:

At the tangency point, we must have equal derivatives, so find out what $x$ must be at that tangency point (in terms of $a$). Also, at the tangency point the two curves must meet, so you can use the found value of $x$ to compare the positions of the two curves at the purported tangency point. That will give you a quadratic equation in $a$.

Along the way, note that you will need to divide by $a-1$, so check that $a$ cannot be $1$ before doing that.

Comment: So basically, on short, find $f_a'(x)=0$ and put that $x_0$ in $f_a(x)$? then get a quadratic in $a$ and just find $a$ with the necessary restrictions? if that is I  will calculate right now and come back in 5m in

Comment: This answer is precisely what I was hinting at with my comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772472/find-a-in-mathbbr-a-neq-0-such-that-the-parabolas-of-the-functions-f-and#comment5717522_2772472

Comment: @C.Cristi: Correct.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan: Of course; I understood that. Though I think the asker missed the point in your comment, inadvertently. =)

Answer (score 0):

$f_a(x)
=ax^2-(a+2)x-1
$,
$g_a(x)=x^2-x-a
$.
Their tangents are
$f_a'(x)
=2ax-(a+2)
$,
$g_a'(x)=2x-1
$.

The tangents have 
the same slope when
$2ax-(a+2)
=2x-1
$
or
$2x(a-1) = a+1
$
or 
$x = \frac{a+1}{2(a-1)}$
(if $a \ne 1$).

If $a=1$ then
$f_a=g_a$
so the curves are identical.

They intersect when
$ax^2-(a+2)x-1
=x^2-x-a
$
or
$(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+a-1
=0
$.

To have the same slope there,
we must have

$\begin{array}\
0
&=(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+a-1\\
&=(a-1)(\frac{a+1}{2(a-1)})^2-(a+1)(\frac{a+1}{2(a-1)})+a-1\\
&=\frac{(a+1)^2}{4(a-1)}-\frac{(a+1)^2}{2(a-1)}+a-1\\
&=-\frac{(a+1)^2}{4(a-1)}+a-1\\
&=\frac{4(a-1)^2-(a+1)^2}{4(a-1)}\\
&=\frac{3a^2-10a+3}{4(a-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$3a^2-10a+3
=0$
or
$a
=\dfrac{10\pm\sqrt{100-36}}{6}
=\dfrac{10\pm\sqrt{64}}{6}
=\dfrac{10\pm 8}{6}
=\dfrac{18, 2}{6}
=3, \frac13
$.

For
$a=3$,
$x = \frac{4}{2(2)}
=1
$
and for
$a=\frac13$,
$x
=\frac{\frac43}{2(-\frac23)}
=-1
$.